# ¿Cómo crear un menú de configuraciones?

Tags: java, android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Buenas tardes

Como sabrán ya he terminado mi app en la plataforma de Android Studio, ahora ya como segunda fase del proyecto, es darle poco a poco mejoras, y una de ella es, el crear un menú de configuración, para ser mas exacto, que en la parte del login en la parte del action bar tenga la opción de configurar conexión, la cual sera ingresar la dirección ip del webservices a la cual se tendrá que conectar.

Así que estoy abierto a comentario y forma de realizarlo, la verdad es que no tengo idea de como implementarlo, les dejo la pantalla de activity, yo lo que tenia pensado es que al momento de seleccionar configurar conexión me abriera una pantalla o textview donde se puede ingresar la ip y se haga la conexión y el usuario pueda usar la app.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

código mandar a llamar webservices y metodo

```
public class webService {

    //Namespace of the Webservice - can be found in WSDL
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://ONControl_MobileWSCore/";
    //Webservice URL - WSDL File location
    private static String URL = "http://MIIP/ONControl_MobileWSCore.asmx";//Make sure you changed IP address
    //SOAP Action URI again Namespace + Web method name
    private static String METHOD_NAME = "Login";
    //private static List arraylist;

    public static String Login(String Usuario,
                               String Contrasena,
                               String Conexion)
    {
        String Resultado = "";
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://MI IP/","Login");
        request.addProperty("Usuario", Usuario);
        request.addProperty("Contrasena", Contrasena);
        request.addProperty("Conexion", Conexion);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes=false;
        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,7000);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            // Invoke web service
            androidHttpTransport.call("http://MI IP/Login", envelope);
            //String ss = androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            Resultado=response.toString();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'
            //menu.errored = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Resultado;
    }


    public static String LLenarEncabezadoCXCP(int Recurso,
                                           String Accion,
                                           int Id,
                                           int Empresa,
                                           String Folio,
                                           Date Fecha,
                                           int Cliente,
                                           int Proveedor,
                                           int Moneda,
                                           double TipoCambio,
                                           int BancoCuenta,
                                           String UsuarioCaptura,
                                           int PagoForma,
                                           double Saldo,
                                           double Importe,
                                           double Financiamiento,
                                           double Descuento,
                                           double SubTotal,
                                           double Retencion1,
                                           double Retencion2,
                                           double IEPS,
                                           double IVA,
                                           double ISH,
                                           double Total,
                                           double TotalAplicado,
                                           String Status,
                                           String UsuarioCancela,
                                           double Numero1,
                                           double Numero2,
                                           double Numero3,
                                           double Numero4,
                                           double Numero5,
                                           double Numero6,
                                           double Numero7,
                                           double Numero8,
                                           double Numero9,
                                           double Numero10,
                                           String Texto1,
                                           String Texto2,
                                           String Texto3,
                                           String Texto4,
                                           String Texto5,
                                           String Texto6,
                                           String Texto7,
                                           String Texto8,
                                           String Texto9,
                                           String Texto10,
                                           Date Fecha1,
                                           Date Fecha2,
                                           Date Fecha3,
                                           Date Fecha4,
                                           Date Fecha5,
                                           Date Fecha6,
                                           String Observacion,
                                           int Catalogo1,
                                           int Catalogo2,
                                           int Catalogo3,
                                           int Catalogo4,
                                           int Catalogo5,
                                           int Catalogo6,
                                           String OrdenCompra,
                                           int Concepto,
                                           String ObservacionCancelacion,
                                           int OrigenVentaCompra,
                                           int OrigenInventario) {

        String Resultado="";
        DateFormat DateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        DecimalFormat numberFormat  = new DecimalFormat("0.00000");

        // Create request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9021/", "LLenarEncabezadoCXCP");
        request.addProperty("Recurso", Recurso);
        request.addProperty("Accion", Accion);
        request.addProperty("Id", Id);
        request.addProperty("Empresa", Empresa);
        request.addProperty("Folio", Folio);
        request.addProperty("Fecha", DateFormatter.format(Fecha));
        request.addProperty("Cliente", Cliente);
        request.addProperty("Proveedor", Proveedor);
        request.addProperty("Moneda", Moneda);
        request.addProperty("TipoCambio",  numberFormat.format(TipoCambio));
        request.addProperty("BancoCuenta", BancoCuenta);
        request.addProperty("UsuarioCaptura", UsuarioCaptura);
        request.addProperty("PagoForma", PagoForma);
        request.addProperty("Saldo", numberFormat.format(Saldo));
        request.addProperty("Importe", numberFormat.format(Importe));
        request.addProperty("Financiamiento", numberFormat.format(Financiamiento));
        request.addProperty("Descuento", numberFormat.format(Descuento));
        request.addProperty("SubTotal", numberFormat.format(SubTotal));
        request.addProperty("Retencion1", numberFormat.format(Retencion1));
        request.addProperty("Retencion2", numberFormat.format(Retencion2));
        request.addProperty("IEPS", numberFormat.format(IEPS));
        request.addProperty("IVA", numberFormat.format(IVA));
        request.addProperty("ISH", numberFormat.format(ISH));
        request.addProperty("Total", numberFormat.format(Total));
        request.addProperty("TotalAplicado", numberFormat.format(TotalAplicado));
        request.addProperty("Status", Status);
        request.addProperty("UsuarioCancela", UsuarioCancela);
        request.addProperty("Numero1", numberFormat.format(Numero1));
        request.addProperty("Numero2", numberFormat.format(Numero2));
        request.addProperty("Numero3", numberFormat.format(Numero3));
        request.addProperty("Numero4", numberFormat.format(Numero4));
        request.addProperty("Numero5", numberFormat.format(Numero5));
        request.addProperty("Numero6", numberFormat.format(Numero6));
        request.addProperty("Numero7", numberFormat.format(Numero7));
        request.addProperty("Numero8", numberFormat.format(Numero8));
        request.addProperty("Numero9", numberFormat.format(Numero9));
        request.addProperty("Numero10", numberFormat.format(Numero10));
        request.addProperty("Texto1", Texto1);
        request.addProperty("Texto2", Texto2);
        request.addProperty("Texto3", Texto3);
        request.addProperty("Texto4", Texto4);
        request.addProperty("Texto5", Texto5);
        request.addProperty("Texto6", Texto6);
        request.addProperty("Texto7", Texto7);
        request.addProperty("Texto8", Texto8);
        request.addProperty("Texto9", Texto9);
        request.addProperty("Texto10", Texto10);
        request.addProperty("Fecha1", DateFormatter.format(Fecha1));
        request.addProperty("Fecha2", DateFormatter.format(Fecha2));
        request.addProperty("Fecha3", DateFormatter.format(Fecha3));
        request.addProperty("Fecha4", DateFormatter.format(Fecha4));
        request.addProperty("Fecha5", DateFormatter.format(Fecha5));
        request.addProperty("Fecha6", DateFormatter.format(Fecha6));
        request.addProperty("Observacion", Observacion);
        request.addProperty("Catalogo1", Catalogo1);
        request.addProperty("Catalogo2", Catalogo2);
        request.addProperty("Catalogo3", Catalogo3);
        request.addProperty("Catalogo4", Catalogo4);
        request.addProperty("Catalogo5", Catalogo5);
        request.addProperty("Catalogo6", Catalogo6);
        request.addProperty("OrdenCompra", OrdenCompra);
        request.addProperty("Concepto", Concepto);
        request.addProperty("ObservacionCancelacion", ObservacionCancelacion);
        request.addProperty("OrigenVentaCompra", OrigenVentaCompra);
        request.addProperty("OrigenInventario", OrigenInventario);


        // Property which holds input parameters

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes = false;
        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 7000);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            // Invoke web service
            androidHttpTransport.call("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9021/LLenarEncabezadoCXCP", envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            Resultado=response.toString();
         } catch (Exception e) {
        //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'
        //menu.errored = true;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        return Resultado;
    }


    public static String LLenarDetalleCXCP(int Recurso,
                                           String Accion,
                                           int Id,
                                           int Origen,
                                           int OrigenDocumento,
                                           double Importe,
                                           double Financiamiento,
                                           double Descuento,
                                           double SubTotal,
                                           double Retencion1,
                                           double Retencion2,
                                           double IEPS,
                                           double IVA,
                                           double ISH,
                                           double Total,
                                           double Saldo,
                                           String Referencia) {

        String resultado = "";
        DecimalFormat numberFormat  = new DecimalFormat("0.00000");

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9021/", "LLenarDetalleCXCP");
        request.addProperty("Recurso", Recurso);
        request.addProperty("Accion", Accion);
        request.addProperty("Id", Id);
        request.addProperty("Origen", Origen);
        request.addProperty("OrigenDocumento", OrigenDocumento);
        request.addProperty("Importe", numberFormat.format(Importe));
        request.addProperty("Financiamiento", numberFormat.format(Financiamiento));
        request.addProperty("Descuento", numberFormat.format(Descuento));
        request.addProperty("SubTotal", numberFormat.format(SubTotal));
        request.addProperty("Retencion1", numberFormat.format(Retencion1));
        request.addProperty("Retencion2", numberFormat.format(Retencion2));
        request.addProperty("IEPS", numberFormat.format(IEPS));
        request.addProperty("IVA", numberFormat.format(IVA));
        request.addProperty("ISH", numberFormat.format(ISH));
        request.addProperty("Total", numberFormat.format(Total));
        request.addProperty("Saldo", numberFormat.format(Saldo));
        request.addProperty("Referencia", Referencia);
        // Property which holds input parameters

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes = false;
        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 7000);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            // Invoke web service
            androidHttpTransport.call("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9021/LLenarDetalleCXCP", envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            resultado=response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'
            //menu.errored = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return resultado;
    }


    public static String GrabarCxCP(int Recurso,
                                     int Modulo,
                                     int Operacion,
                                     int Documento,
                                     int OrigenId,
                                     int OrigenDocumento)
    {

        String resultado = "";
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://MIIP/", "GrabarCXCP");
        request.addProperty("Recurso", Recurso);
        request.addProperty("Modulo", Modulo);
        request.addProperty("Operacion", Operacion);
        request.addProperty("Documento", Documento);
        request.addProperty("OrigenId", OrigenId);
        request.addProperty("OrigenDocumento", OrigenDocumento);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes = false;
        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 7000);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            // Invoke web service
            androidHttpTransport.call("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9021/GrabarCXCP", envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            resultado=response.toString();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'


            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         return resultado;
    }

    public static ArrayList<FormaPago> FormaPago()
    {

        String resultado = "";
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9021/", "CatalogoGeneral");
        request.addProperty("Id", 0);
        request.addProperty("Clave", "");
        request.addProperty("Descripcion", "");
        request.addProperty("FiltroAdicional", "");
        request.addProperty("Catalogo", "sp_pagoforma");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes = false;
        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 7000);

        ArrayList<FormaPago> DetalleArray = new ArrayList<FormaPago>();

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            // Invoke web service
            androidHttpTransport.call("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9021/CatalogoGeneral", envelope);
            //String ss = androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
            SoapObject SO_FormaPago = (SoapObject)((SoapObject)((SoapObject) envelope.getResponse()).getProperty(1)).getProperty(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < SO_FormaPago.getPropertyCount(); i++) {

                FormaPago newDetalle = new FormaPago(ONC_SYS.NullToZeroInteger(webService.WSGetPropertyNull("Id", (SoapObject) SO_FormaPago.getProperty(i))),
                        webService.WSGetPropertyNull("Clave", (SoapObject) SO_FormaPago.getProperty(i)),
                        webService.WSGetPropertyNull("Descripcion", (SoapObject) SO_FormaPago.getProperty(i)));


                DetalleArray.add(newDetalle);


            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'
            //menu.errored = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Return booleam to calling object
        //return loginStatus;

        return DetalleArray;


    }


    private static String WSGetPropertyNull(String PropertyName, SoapObject O_SP)
    {
        if (O_SP.hasProperty(PropertyName)== true)
        {
            return O_SP.getProperty(PropertyName).toString();
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }


}


Erro al guardar la ip del servidor

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile, PID: 11120
                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                      at mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile.Login$2.onClick(Login.java:130)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:157)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


Codigo Alertdialog

 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // action with ID action_refresh was selected
            case R.id.action_settings:
                try {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("Ingresa Dirección IP  del Servidor");

//Creamos el input text y asignamos el tipo de EditText que     necesitamos
                    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
                    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT );
                    builder.setView(input); //Lo agregamos a la vista

// Agregamos los botones de Guardar/Cancelar
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Guardar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //Almacenamos la preferencia y la dirección ip colocada
                            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                            editor.putString(" ", input.getText().toString());
                            editor.commit();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    builder.show();
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    Log.e("ERROR",ex.getMessage());
                }

                break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


este es mi mtodo del del recuperado de mi preferencia y el llamdo de mi metodo

public class webService {

    Context context;
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String URLCONEXION = prefs.getString("ONControlWSURL","");

    //Namespace of the Webservice - can be found in WSDL
    //private static String NAMESPACE = "http://ONControl_MobileWSCore/";
    //Webservice URL - WSDL File location
    private static String URL = "http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9021/ONControl_MobileWSCore.asmx";//Make sure you changed IP address
    private String ONControlWS = URLCONEXION;//Make sure you changed IP address
    //SOAP Action URI again Namespace + Web method name
    //private static String METHOD_NAME = "Login";
    //private static List arraylist;

    public String Login(String Usuario,
                        String Contrasena,
                        String Conexion)
    {
        String Resultado = "";
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(ONControlWS,"Login");
        request.addProperty("Usuario", Usuario);
        request.addProperty("Contrasena", Contrasena);
        request.addProperty("Conexion", Conexion);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes=false;
        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,7000);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            // Invoke web service
            androidHttpTransport.call(ONControlWS+"/Login", envelope);
            //String ss = androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            Resultado=response.toString();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'
            //menu.errored = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Resultado;
    }
```

Comment: Te dejo respuesta si quieres realizar una vista de preferencias, pero en caso que solo quieras ingresar lo del servidor ip, con un cuadro de dialogo te bastaría.

Comment: si, solo por el momento requiero de ingresar la ip y que se guarde y que funcione mis metodos.

Comment: Entonces mirate la respuesta de AngelRuizC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si unicamente necesitas almacenar y modificar ese dato (IP del Servidor) te recomiendo que mejor uses un AlertDialog con un EditText para que se coloque la dirección IP y esta a su vez almacenarla como una preferencia (SharedPreference) y listo, te evitas el tener que crear otro layout, otra activity, etc...

Puedes crear el dialogo mediante un layout pero si no necesitas ningún estilo te recomiendo hacerlo por código. Espero que te sirva.

```
public void abrirDialogoConfiguracion() {
try{
//Declaramos el AlertDialog que aparecera
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Dirección del servidor");

//Creamos el input text y asignamos el tipo de EditText que     necesitamos
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT );
builder.setView(input); //Lo agregamos a la vista

// Agregamos los botones de Guardar/Cancelar 
builder.setPositiveButton("Guardar", new    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    //Almacenamos la preferencia y la dirección ip colocada
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString(“ip_servidor”,input.getText().ToString());
    editor.commit();
}
});
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    dialog.cancel();
}
});

builder.show();
} catch(Exception ex){
    Log.e("ERROR",ex.getMessage());
}
}
```

Comment: ok, otra duda yo tengo un archivo donde yo mando a llamar el webservices y los metodos, los cuales ya despues yo mando a llamar, como haria la referencia de mi sharepreference a mi archivo de los metodos, te ajunto el codigo de como lo tengo

Comment: AngelRuiz y como inserto mi alertdialog en el Actionbar? ingreso este metodo que me pones oncreateMenu?

Comment: me marca error al querer guarda la ip, dejo el error y el codigo de mi alertdialog

Comment: ya pude y ya me generar el archivo xml de la preferencia, pero ahora tengo duda de como acceso a esa preferencia me ayudarias a explicarme

Comment: Alguien que me pueda ayudar?

Comment: El metodo que te puse puedes llamarlo desde el oncreateMenu en la opcion que tengas de configuracion, una vez que se presione esa opción te abrirá el cuadro de dialogo y ahi introducimos la dirección IP del servidor y al dar clic en guardar, almacena la preferencia de la aplicación.  Una vez que tengas almacenada la preferencia se puede obtener en cualquier parte de la app de la siguiente manera : SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context); string ipServidor = preferences.getString("ip_servidor", "0.0.0.0"); //Valor default

Comment: Por ultimo para hacer la petición a tus metodos lo puedes hacer concatenando el valor, puedes armar el string de la llamada del metodo de la siguiente manera, ej. string url_servidor = String.format("http://%s/%s",ipServidor,"ObtenerUsuarios"); Esto hara una cadena con el siguiente formato "http://192.168.1.0/ObtenerUsuarios" ya si tu webservice toma parametros por GET o POST ya hay que agregarselos a tu llamada al servidor, si es de tipo GET los puedes concatenar ahi mismo en la url, ej. "http://192.168.1.0/ObtenerUsuarios?id=101&pass=holamundo"

Comment: me manda un error ya estoy en la parte de recuperar mi preferencia pero me manda un error en el doInbackground

Comment: amigo te adjunte una imagen logcat del error y el codigo donde recupero mi preference y lo mando a mi metodo login

Comment: Puede colocar todo el logcat completo del error para poder darle un vistazo por favor

Comment: te acabo de adjuntar las imagenes

Comment: si sabras que es?

Comment: En las imagenes que pusiste, indica un NullPointerException, puedes debuugear tu procedimiento de la llamada al servidor para ver en que momento arroja la excepcion y revisar la propiedar getMessage() de tu variable de excepcion para tener un detalle más especifico del error

Comment: ya quedo amigo si me sirvio tu sugerencia...

Comment: gracias por el apoyo

Answer (score 2):

Con Android Studio puedes crear la vista de preferencias con lo siguiente.

`New->Activity->Gallery` y seleccionas `Settings Activity`

en el directorio `res/xml` encontrarás los layouts de la sección preferencias

`pref_headers.xml` es donde habrán las secciones de preferencias, si la aplicación se visualiza en una tablet, se mostrarán con selectores a la izquierda y a la derecha la sección de preferencias seleccionada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en `pref_general.xml` puedes poner

```
<EditTextPreference
        android:key="servidorip"
        android:title="Servidor ip"
        android:summary="Dirección de los datos"
        android:defaultValue="0.0.0.0"
        android:dialogTitle="Inserta Dirección IP" />
```

y para obtener en otra actividad lo que se ha configurado

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String imgSett = prefs.getString("servidorip", "0.0.0.0");
```

Android Studio te genera una vista de preferencias con datos, si los quieres eliminar debes se cauteloso, entender primero la estructura que ha generado, para ello puedes usar el panel `structure` izquierda bajo lo de `project`